# Integral of a numerical second derivative

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to find the integral $M(r)$ of a second derivative of equation $f(r)$ where this equation has only a numerical solution
`sol = NDSolve[f[r],...]`.

```
M[r]=Integrate[the second derivative of f(r),{r,0,10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because lack of example code I show the principal way to solve the problem:

Create NDSolve solution `f[r]`

```
f = NDSolveValue[{F'[r] + F[r] == 0, F[0] == 1}, F, {r, 0, 10}]
```

Integrate NDSolve result `f''[r]`

```
NIntegrate[f''[r], {r, 0, 10}]
(*0.999955*)
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the original call has a form something like the following:

```
sol = NDSolve[f[r], u, {r, 0, 10}] (* OP says f[r] is an 'equation' but does
                                      not indicate the dependent variable 
                                      or boundary conditions              *)
```

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the answer should be given by

```
u'[10] - u'[0] /. sol
```

This will return the value(s) for the integral, one for each solution returned by `NDSolve`. (A nonlinear `f[r]` may have more than one solution.)